# How to handle kafka consumer failures

Tags: apache-kafka

> I am trying understand how to handle failed consumer records. How to
> we know there is record failure. What I am seeing is when the record
> processing failed in the consumer with runtime exception consumer is
> keep on retrying. But when the next record is available to process it
> is commiting offset of the latest record, which is expected. My
> question how to we know about failed record. In older messaging
> systems failed messages are rolled back to queues and processing stops
> there. Then we know the queue is down and we can take action.

I can record the failed record into some db table,but what happens if this recording fails?
I can move failures to error/ dead letter queues, again what happens if this moving fails?

I am using kafka 2.6 with spring boot 2.3.4. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would need to disable auto commits and manually commit the offsets yourself when your scope of "sucessfully processed" is achieved. If you include external processes like a database, then you will also need to increase Kafka client timeouts so it doesnt think the consumer is dead while waiting on error logging/handling.

Comment: Event with auto commits off, it is going to process the next record after the failure and commit the next offset.  auto commit off is not going to stop consuming messages after the failure. Am I right? Again my question How do we know about the failed record?

Comment: If you disable commits, then discard the remaining records from the poll (after commiting successful record offsets), then polling again will retry the failed records

Comment: Thank you for you quick response. That should work for me. I am using spring boot 2.3.4 with kafka listener. I just started still learning kafka. Can you please help in how to start kafka listener from the failed record. Looks like I need to start listener dynamaically after the failure. For ex, if there db connection failure on one record then I will stop committing offsets from there after. When the connection issue got recovered then how do I need to start a listener without code change. I need to admin client apis to start one like that?

Comment: Like I said, on the next poll, it'll start from any uncommitted offsets, which in this scenario, would be the most recent failed record. I dont use Spring, but I assume KafkaListener should be continously running